# transform SVG path via css in Edge

Tags: css, svg, path, transform

I have an inline SVG and I'm trying to use

```
transform: translateY(225px);
-ms-transform: translateY(225px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(225px);
```

on one of it's paths. It works in all browsers exept in MS Edge. In Edge I can transform whole svg but paths inside don't.

Comment: Last I checked, you can't transform SVG elements in IE/Edge. You can only style SVG [properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#chapter-propidx) in IE.